# DialgFlowApp ask method, reprompt not working

Tags: actions-on-google

According to the DialogFlowApp/ask documentation 'https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/DialogflowApp#ask)  you should be able to provide 3 reprompts when the user is silent. I have tried the following code :

```
let PROMPT = [
"Are you still here?",
"Should we stop the conversation",
"bye"];


let answer = "welcome to the application";

const app = new DialogflowApp({request, response});

app.ask(answer, PROMPT);
```

on a goole home device. The device does reprompt the silent user with its own predefined answer but is not using the one provided. 
Did anybody could make this work ?

Thank in anticipation,

Thierry

Comment: Can you post the log that would be printed out when you ask `app.ask`?

Comment: Sorry which log are you talking about ? My architecture : node is running on my Linux/PC which is accessed by dialogflow through an ngrok tunneling.

Comment: Server/ngrok logs. I'm curious to see if there is an issue with getting your `PROMPT` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was able to get it to work using the code that you presented. I demonstrated on video here: https://youtu.be/GpMjpo4hSR4

I used the inline editor in Dialogflow.
https://dialogflow.com/docs/how-tos/getting-started-fulfillment

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time !  I don't get why I wasn't able to make it work then.will redo the test. One possibility though is that I was doing the test in French. Will test with both languages